# Treating external shed wall in a tight space

Tags: shed

Can anyone offer tips or tricks on how best to treat an external shed wall that is 12 inches from a boundary fence?

Comment: A six pack, a teenager and a paint roller.

Comment: Why are you "treating" the wall, and with what? What kind of fence? How tall is it? Easy to remove / unbolt some of it?

Comment: What's the boundary fence made of?  Pailings?  Does it face onto another property or onto a road or something else?   Can you simply un-clad (?) the fence - strip it of the covering for the duration of your work ?   Adding a photo of your wall would help a heap.